# Connecting to a Gateway Service

Tags: c#, gateway

I am trying to connect to a gateway service:

The Service says this when I "Add Web Reference" to the service it says:

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

The gateway service shows this:

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the
>   command line with the following syntax:
>
> > svcutil.exe http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/API/Gateway.svc?wsdl
>
> This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains
>   the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use
>   the generated client class to call the Service. For example:
>
> C#
>
> class Test {
>       static void Main()
>       {
>           GatewayClient client = new GatewayClient();
>
> ```
>     // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
>
>     // Always close the client.
>     client.Close();
> } }
> ```
>
> Visual Basic
>
> Class Test
>       Shared Sub Main()
>           Dim client As GatewayClient = New GatewayClient()
>           ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
>
> ```
>     ' Always close the client.
>     client.Close()
> End Sub End Class
> ```

So, I try connecting to this instead:

http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/API/Gateway.svc?wsdl

That gives me the following list:

> Methods AddABAccount ( )  CloseBatch ( )  CopyVaultAccount ( ) 
>   ProcessAccount ( )  ProcessCustomer ( )  ProcessCustomerAndAccount ( )
>   ProcessTransaction ( )  ProcessVaultTransaction ( )  UpdateABAccount (
>   )  UpdateABSchedule ( )  UpdateTransaction ( )

So, I am able to add it...

But, when I try to connect to it in code as they suggests:

```
GatewayClient Client = new GatewayClient("wsBinding");
TRANSACTION oT = new TRANSACTION();
GATEWAYRESPONSE oGr = new GATEWAYRESPONSE();
oT.AMOUNT = 1;
oT.TEST = "FALSE"; // When testing, use TRUE
oT.METHOD = "CC"; // We'll use a credit card
oT.ORDERID = GetOrderID(); // Define a unique id for each transaction
oT.CODE = "0000"; // An Auth only transaction
//Process the Transaction
oGr = Client.ProcessTransaction(oT);
//Close the Client
Client.Close();
if (oGr.TRANSACTIONRESPONSE.RESPONSE_CODE == "1")
{
//Handle approved transaction
}
else if (oGr.TRANSACTIONRESPONSE.RESPONSE_CODE == "2")
{
//Handle declined transaction
}
else
{
//Handle transaction error
}
```

I am not able to access GatewayClient, it says:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'GatewayClient'

Where do I find GatewayClient!?

Comment: You're getting the _Cannot resolve symbol_ error at compile time, correct?

Comment: I get it in the visual studio before I attempt to compile.

Comment: What name did you give your service reference when you created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a *Web Reference* you are trying to add a reference to an oldfashioned .asmx Web Service.

The Service you actually try to reference is a WCF Web Service - starting with Visual Studio 2008 when adding a service reference WCF Web Services are the preferred option (you'll have to dig to some "advanced" options to add an .asmx Web Service).

To use the Web Service client proxy created for you, make sure to include the namespace in your `using` statements.

The default namespace that is set when adding the Service Reference is "ServiceReference1", so adding

```
using ServiceReference1;
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah this helped! I was adding it as a Web Reference instead of a Service Method. Once I did that, it added the appropriated dlls. The reference to the Web Service was there but it wasn't added correctly. Thank you!